# Can one change the number/order of comments?

Tags: comments, powerpoint-2010

I wanted to use comments (little markers with my initials and a number) on some PowerPoint slides showing a flow of events to provide an indication in which order things happen and - since the comments pop up when hovering over the marker - at the same time provide short explanations for each event.

However, due to some editing the numbers ended up to be noncontiguous and they also don't start with 1 but the series starts with 3. Thus my questions: can one control the order and the numbers being used for these comments? I.e.:
a. How do I control the starting number?
b. How can I reorder (or re-assign) comment numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I actually changed my entire approach and used [this](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00691_Use_VBA_to_create_popup_text.htm) very useful description to create mouse-hover popups using a VBA macro. It works quite nicely. The only wish I have would be, that the automatically created text-boxes would also automatically disappear again when leaving the area with the mouse (instead of having to click into them)...

Comment: It takes a bit more work, but it can be done.  You create two shapes, one the visible one that you'll hover the mouse over, the other a slightly larger shape, set directly behind the first shape and either made the same color as the first shape or set to e.g. 99% transparent; the idea is to make it invisible.  Set its mouseover action to run another macro that undoes whatever the mouseover on the first shape did.